# Installation of custom SPWindowsService

Tags: service-application, service

In my solution I have Windows Service, that I want to control from SharePoint. I implemented custom SPWindowsService and SPWindowsServiceInstance, it works from tests (Start, Stop and deploy credentials works as a charm).

Now it is time to install it. It looks like it could be implemented as SPFeatureReceiver. Current code looks like this:

```
[Guid("a02af039-3e4a-408c-8b6b-1b3e297af978")]
public class XxxxEventReceiver : SPFeatureReceiver
{
    public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {

        var service = SPFarm.Local.Services.GetValue<XxxxService>(XxxxService.ServiceName);
        if (service == null)
        {
            service = new XxxxService(SPFarm.Local);
            service.Update();                

            var instance = new XxxxServiceInstance(service);                
            instance.Update();

            instance.Provision();

            TempTrace.Info("XxxxEventReceiver - FeatureActivated");
        }            
    }

    public override void FeatureUninstalling(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        var service = SPFarm.Local.Services
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == XxxxService.ServiceName);

        if (service != null)
        {
            foreach (var instance in service.Instances)
            {
                instance.Delete();
            }

            service.Delete();
            TempTrace.Info("XxxxEventReceiver - FeatureUninstalling");
        }
    }
}
```

Main problem is "instance.Provision();". This line leads to the exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot start service Xxxx on computer '.'. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start(String[] args)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Win32.SPAdvApi32.StartService(String strServiceName)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWindowsServiceInstance.Start()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWindowsServiceInstance.Provision(Boolean start)
at Xxxxx.SharePoint.Features.Xxxx.XxxxEventReceiver.FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.DoActivationCallout(Boolean fActivate, Boolean fForce)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.Activate(SPSite siteParent, SPWeb webParent, SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAdminFeatureCollection.Add(Guid featid, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, Boolean fForce)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternal(SPFeatureDefinition featdef, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean force, Boolean fMarkOnly)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinitionCollection.AddCore(SPFeatureDefinition featdef, SPSite site, String solutionHash, Boolean fForce, Boolean fDoValidation)
```

So issue is that during activation, it does not have enough permissions and I do not know how to solve this.

Questions:

1. How to implement installation(provisioning) of the custom SPWindowsService ?
2. How to execute provisioning with more privileges?
3. Is there any code examples in public that shows how to implement custom SPWindowsService with installation?

Comment: Have you tried adding the account running the code as Local Administrator? This is against best practice, but it will help you determine if the problem lays in permissions.

Comment: Account is Local Administrator, I try to install feature from Visual Studio. UAC is disabled.

Comment: But the code is probably executed as the App Pool account, depending on the scope of your feature?

Comment: It is farm-scoped feature.

Comment: Code runs under my account. At least Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity is me :)

Comment: That is a bit odd, since Farm scoped feature receivers runs with very high permissions. But if that is the case, that is the case :)